# Error creating DbContext for ApplicationDbContext wont work

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Im using .net 6 and it wont create a migration for me and I keep getting the error stated in the title above. I tried many different things such as using the dotnet ef cli instead of the nuget package manager console but nothign will work.

```
using AUTHENTICATION.SERVICE;
using AUTHENTICATION.SERVICE.Database;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    // TODO: REPLACE THIS LATER WHEN ADDING KUBERNETES AND DOCKER.
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDBConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddInMemoryClients(OAuthConfig.Clients())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(OAuthConfig.IdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(OAuthConfig.ApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(OAuthConfig.ApiScopes())
    .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseRouting();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Comment: Can you please add the command you're running to create the migration, and the solution / folder structure?

Comment: @lizardcoder are you using separate layer for database something like DAL Layer..

Comment: @VikramSingh i am not using any seperate data layer for this

Comment: @MattU im doing Add-Migration AddIdentityUsersToDb

Comment: whats not making sense is my application when i start it , it runs without problems and not only that but it even creates the entity framework migrations table in the database.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/XFZ8lVlyYQFd.png this is my file structure